# FPDF Generate individual pages instead of one big One

Tags: php, mysql, fpdf

I am trying to generate multi pages on fpdf for each email in the array, but it keeps generating a long page with data for each email and sends that long page to everyone.
**UPDATE**
This is my whole code... the first part generates PDF and the second emails them.

```
<?php
while (ob_get_level())
ob_end_clean();
header("Content-Encoding: None", true);

//Requires here     
require('../fpdf/fpdf.php');
require_once '../connect.php';

$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mcle','user','pass'); 
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

// CREATE AND SAVE THE PDF DOCUMENT
class pdf extends FPDF
{

function header()
{

//$this->image('img/lsnc_logo.jpg',2,2);
$this->SetTextColor(0,0,255);
$this->SetFont('Helvetica','B',16);
$this->SetFillColor('230,230,230');
$this->SetXY(35,15); 
$this->Cell(140,10,'Certificate Of Attendance for California 
MCLE',1,0,'C', TRUE);
$this->Ln(20);
} 
function pdf_body($db)
{   
$emails = $_POST['email']; 
foreach ($emails as $email)
{
$stmt = $db->query("SELECT * 
FROM sessions JOIN attendance 
ON sessions.event_id = attendance.event_id JOIN staff 
ON attendance.staff_bar_no = staff.staff_bar_no
WHERE staff.email = '$email'");
for($i = 0; $i < count($emails); $i++)
{

while($data = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ))
{

$this->Ln(10);
$this->SetX(20);
$this->SetFont('Arial','B',11);             
$this->Cell(45,6,'Provider Name:',0,0,'R',0);

$this->SetFont('Times','',11);
$this->Cell(150,6,'Legal Services Of Northern California',0,0,'L');
$this->Ln();

$this->SetX(20);
$this->SetFont('Arial','B',11);             
$this->Cell(45,6,'Provider Number:',0,0,'R',0);
$this->SetFont('Times','',11);
$this->Cell(150,6,'2221',0,0,'L');
$this->Ln();

$this->SetX(20);
$this->SetFont('Arial','B',11);             
$this->Cell(45,6,'Title Of Activity:',0,0,'R',0);

$this->SetFont('Times','',11);
$this->Cell(150,6,$data->pro_title,0,0,'L');
$this->Ln();

$this->SetX(20);
$this->SetFont('Arial','B',11); 
$this->Cell(45,6,'Date Of Activity:',0,0,'R',0);
$this->SetFont('Times','',11);
$this->Cell(65,6,$data->date,0,0,'L');
$this->Ln();                

$this->SetX(20);
$this->SetFont('Arial','B',11); 
$this->Cell(45,6,'Time of Activity:',0,0,'R',0);
$this->SetFont('Times','',11);
$this->Cell(65,6,$data->time,0,0,'L');
$this->Ln();

$this->SetX(20);
$this->SetFont('Arial','B',11); 
$this->Cell(45,6,'Location (City, State):',0,0,'R',0);
$this->SetFont('Times','',11);
$this->Cell(150,6,$data->location,0,0,'L');
$this->Ln();


$this->Ln(10);
$this->SetFont('Arial','B',12);
$this->Cell(65,6,'Eligible California MCLE Credit','',0);
$this->Ln(10);

$this->SetFont('Times','',12);
$this->Cell(109,6,'Total California MCLE Credit Hours for the above 
activity are:',0,0,'R',0);
$this->SetFont('Times','B',12);
$this->Cell(4,6,$data->length,0,0,'R');
$this->SetFont('Times','',12);
$this->Cell(80,6,', including the following sub-field 
credits:',0,0,'L',0);
$this->Ln(5);

$this->SetFont('Arial','',12);  
$this->Cell(45,6,'* Legal Ethics: ',0,0,'R',0);
$this->SetFont('Arial','B',12); 
$this->Cell(45,6,$data->length,0,0,'L');
$this->Ln();


$this->SetFont('Arial','',12);  
$this->Cell(57,6,'* Elimination of Bias: ',0,0,'R',0);
$this->SetFont('Arial','B',12);
$this->Cell(45,6,$data->bias,0,0,'L');
$this->Ln();

$this->SetFont('Arial','',12);  
$this->Cell(174,6,'* Substance Abuse / Mental or Physical Issues Affecting 
Professional Competence: ',0,0,'R',0);
$this->SetFont('Arial','B',12);
$this->Cell(10,6,$data->sampiapc,0,0,'L');
$this->SetFont('Arial','',12);  


$this->Ln(15);  
$this->SetFont('Times','B',11);             
$this->MultiCell(174,6,'THE BOTTOM PORTION OF THIS FORM IS TO BE COMPLETED 
BY THE ATTORNEY AFTER PARTICIPATION IN THE ABOVE-REFERENCED ACTIVITY');

$this->Ln(12);
// Split Here 
$this->SetFont('Times','I',12);     
$this->SetX(20);
$this->MultiCell(170, 6, '' . str_repeat('By signing below, I certify that 
I participated in all or some* of the activity described above and am 
therefore entitled to the following MCLE credit hours -', 1),'LRT');

$this->SetFont('Times','',12);
$this->SetX(20);
$this->Cell(170,6,'Total California MCLE Credit Hours ______, including 
the following sub-field credits:','LR');

$this->Ln();
$this->SetX(20);
$this->SetFont('Times','',12);  
$this->Cell(170,6,'         Legal Ethics:______','LR');
$this->Ln();

$this->SetX(20);            
$this->SetFont('Times','',12);  
$this->Cell(170,6,'         Elimination of Bias:______','LR');
$this->Ln();

$this->SetX(20);
$this->SetFont('Times','',12);              
$this->Cell(170,6,'         Substance Abuse / Mental or Physical Issues 
Affecting Professional Competence:____ ','LR');
$this->Ln();


$this->SetFont('Times','I',12); 
$this->SetX(20);    
$this->Cell(170,6,' ','LR');
$this->Ln();
$this->SetX(20);                
$this->MultiCell(170,6,'*Partial participation hours must be pro-rated. 
You may not claim credit for sub-fields unless the Provider is granting 
credit in those areas and you participated in those portions of the 
activity ','LR');

$this->SetX(20);
$this->Cell(170,6,' ','LR');
$this->Ln();

//
$this->SetX(20);
$this->SetFont('Times','',12);  
$this->Cell(33,6,'Print Your Name:',0,'L');
$this->SetFont('Arial','B',12);
$this->Cell(80,6,$data->fname." ".$data->lname ,0,0,'L');

$this->SetFont('Arial','',12);
$this->Cell(28,6,'State Bar No: ',0,'R');
$this->SetFont('Arial','B',12);

$this->Cell(29,6,$data->staff_bar_no,0,0,'L');

$this->SetX(20);
$this->Cell(170,10,' ','LR');
//
$this->Ln();
$this->SetX(20);
$this->SetFont('Times','',12);  
$this->Cell(170,6,'Your Signature:_____________________________ ','LR');

$this->SetX(20);
$this->Cell(170,6,' ','LR');
$this->Ln();
$this->SetX(20);
$this->Cell(170,6,' ','LRB');
$this->Ln(19);


$this->SetFont('Times','B',10); 
$this->SetX(20);
$this->Cell(25,4,'Reminders: ',0,0,'L',0);
$this->Ln();
$this->SetX(20);
$this->SetFont('Times','',10);  
$this->MultiCell(170,4,'1- Keep this record of attendance for 4 years. In 
the event that you are audited by the State Bar, you may be requested to 
submit this record of attendance. Send this to the State Bar only if you 
are audited');
$this->SetX(20);
$this->MultiCell(170,4,'2- You must personally sign-in on the Official 
Record of Attendance for California MCLE or complete a contemporaneous 
registered login online for web events maintained by this provider in 
order to qualify for California MCLE credits.');

}       

}   
}

}

function footer()
{

}
//////////////////////////      Make sure we don't detete this below
}   
//////////////////////////
$pdf = new pdf();
$pdf->AddPage('P','A4',0);
$pdf->pdf_body($db);

//$pdf->Output();
//Mailing Parts here 

$emails = $_POST['email']; //This is mainly to declare $email 
foreach ($emails as $email)
{
//
}

// email stuff (change data below)
$to = $email;
$from = "noreply@domain"; 
$subject = "Your LSNC MCLE Attendance Certificate"; 
$message = "<p>Hello,</p> <p>Here is your LSNC MCLE Attendance 
Certificate. Please Confirm . Thank you !</p>";

// a random hash will be necessary to send mixed content
$separator = md5(time());

// carriage return type (we use a PHP end of line constant)
$eol = PHP_EOL;

// attachment name 
$filename = "MCLE.pdf";

// encode data (puts attachment in proper format)                   
$pdfdoc = $pdf->Output('', 'S');
$attachment = chunk_split(base64_encode($pdfdoc));

// main header
$headers  = "From: ".$from.$eol;
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0".$eol; 
$headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"".$separator."\"";

// no more headers after this, we start the body! //


$body = "--".$separator.$eol;
$body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit".$eol.$eol;
//$body .= "This is a MIME encoded message.".$eol;

// message
$body .= "--".$separator.$eol;
$body .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"".$eol;
$body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit".$eol.$eol;
$body .= $message.$eol;

// attachment
$body .= "--".$separator.$eol;
$body .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; 
name=\"".$filename."\"".$eol; 
$body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64".$eol;
$body .= "Content-Disposition: attachment".$eol.$eol;
$body .= $attachment.$eol;
$body .= "--".$separator."--";
mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers) ;
unset($pdf);  // THIS will now ONLY send the first email with other 
//generated pages...

?>
<script>
alert('Emails Successfully Sent !');
history.back();
</script>
<?php
?>
```

I hope to find a solution for this, I know I am missing on the first loop, I couldn't loop through elements of the array (I think). once I get that right, the email part will work fine as I have tested it on individual records...
Many Thanks @Dave.

Comment: There seems to be a lot missing from  your question. There is no code in there that sends anything to start with. You want to create the PDF if your loop through the emails, send it, then destroy the PDF object before you start through the loop again.

Comment: @Dave, Thank you again for replying, the sending code is fine, it works just fine as it is already working on sending one page.. i just didn't want to include tons of code here but happy to provide it. (Will Update).
This is where i am stuck as this code generates n pages based on the selected array of emails.. but puts them all in one big PDF of n pages... then sends them to all emails in the selected array, what I want however is to send each respective page based on the email.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a `foreach` going through `$_POST['multi1']` and a similar looking `foreach` going through `$_POST['email']` so it isn't clear which of those variables is actually coming from your form (which isn't shown).

I'm going to assume, for this answer, that `$_POST['multi1']` is the correct variable to be using. If it isn't adjust the code as needed. You'll notice that the PDF gets built for each e-mail address, sent and then the PDF object is destroyed before going on to the next e-mail address.

```
// this stuff only needs to be set once
$subject = 'Your LSNC MCLE Attendance Certificate';
$message = '<p>Hello,</p><p>Here is your LSNC MCLE Attendance Certificate. Please Confirm . Thank you!</p>';

// a random hash will be necessary to send mixed content
$separator = md5(time());

// carriage return type (we use a PHP end of line constant)
$eol = PHP_EOL;

// attachment name
$filename = "MCLE.pdf";

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    foreach($_POST['multi1'] as $email) {

        $to = $email;

        $stmt = $db->query("SELECT * FROM sessions
                            JOIN attendance ON sessions.event_id = attendance.event_id
                            JOIN staff      ON attendance.staff_bar_no = staff.staff_bar_no
                            WHERE staff.email = '$email'");

        while ($data = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) {
            //building pdf here
        }

        $pdf = new pdf();
        $pdf->AddPage('P','A4',0);
        $pdf->pdf_body($db);

        // encode data (puts attachment in proper format)

        $pdfdoc = $pdf->Output("", "S");
        $attachment = chunk_split(base64_encode($pdfdoc));

        // main header
        $headers  = 'From: noreply@emailaddress.domain' . $eol;
        $headers .= '"MIME-Version: 1.0' . $eol;
        $headers .= 'Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="' . $separator .'"';

        // no more headers after this, we start the body! //

        $body  = '--' . $separator . $eol;
        $body .= 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit' . $eol . $eol;
        //$body .= "This is a MIME encoded message.".$eol;

        // message
        $body .= '--' . $separator . $eol;
        $body .= 'Content-Type: text/html; charset="iso-8859-1"' . $eol;
        $body .= 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit' . $eol . $eol;
        $body .= $message . $eol;

        // attachment
        $body .= '--' . $separator . $eol;
        $body .= 'Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name="MCLE.pdf"' . $eol;
        $body .= 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64' . $eol;
        $body .= 'Content-Disposition: attachment' . $eol . $eol;
        $body .= $attachment . $eol;
        $body .= '--' . $separator . '--';
        mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers) ;

        unset($pdf);  // destroy PDF object

    }  // end of foreach through $_POST['multi1']

}  // end of isset($_POST['submit'])
```

Comment: This is not working, because I only posted the parts that are not working for me, you probably missed my idea (not that I know what the hell I am doing :-) ) you are the expert.

Comment: Not working isn't helpful at all. Based on what is in your question and the description of the problem it should be very very close to what you need. As I said at the top of the answer the variable names I used may not be correct but that should be a simple fix. Everything else should be correct.

Comment: Thank you so much, I have updated my code to include everything, I was trying to make it simple...
That's my whole php file. as I was mentioning earlier, I am only stuck at the first part I think. 
Thank  you Sir.

Comment: I finally got it to work, but I have to strip my code from a lot of garbage i copied somewhere else !! like $this, I replaced it with $pdf, then got rid of classes, they are evil ! I will post my clean code here so someone needing help can use it.
MANY thanks Dave. I appreciate your patience and prompt help.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what finally worked for me, Thanks to @Dave for his help.

```
<?php
while (ob_get_level())
ob_end_clean();
header("Content-Encoding: None", true);

global $idx; 
global $email; 

//Requires here     
require('../fpdf/fpdf.php');
require_once '../connect.php';

$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mcle','user','pass'); 
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

// this stuff only needs to be set once
$subject = 'Your LSNC MCLE Attendance Certificate';
$message = '<p>Hello,</p><p>Here is your LSNC MCLE Attendance Certificate. Please 
Confirm . Thank you!</p>';

// a random hash will be necessary to send mixed content
$separator = md5(time());

// carriage return type (we use a PHP end of line constant)
$eol = PHP_EOL;

// attachment name
$filename = "MCLE.pdf";

if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
foreach($_POST['email'] as $email)
{
$to = $email;
$stmt = $db->query("SELECT * 
FROM sessions JOIN attendance 
ON sessions.event_id = attendance.event_id JOIN staff 
ON attendance.staff_bar_no = staff.staff_bar_no
WHERE staff.email = '$email'");
while($data = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ))
{
//Header
//$pdf->image('img/lsnc_logo.jpg',2,2);
$pdf = new FPDF();
$pdf->AddPage('P','A4',0);
$pdf->SetTextColor(0,0,255);
$pdf->SetFont('Helvetica','B',16);
$pdf->SetFillColor('230,230,230');
$pdf->SetXY(35,15); 
$pdf->Cell(140,10,'Certificate Of Attendance for California MCLE',1,0,'C', TRUE);
$pdf->Ln(20);

//Body
$pdf->SetTextColor(0,0,0);
$pdf->Ln(10);
$pdf->SetX(20);
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',11);              
$pdf->Cell(45,6,'Provider Name:',0,0,'R',0);

$pdf->SetX(20);
$pdf->SetFont('Times','',12);   
$pdf->Cell(33,6,'Print Your Name:',0,'L');
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',12);
$pdf->Cell(80,6,$data->fname." ".$data->lname ,0,0,'L');

$pdf->SetFont('Arial','',12);
$pdf->Cell(28,6,'State Bar No: ',0,'R');
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',12);

$pdf->Cell(29,6,$data->staff_bar_no,0,0,'L');

$pdf->SetX(20);
$pdf->Cell(170,10,' ','LR');
//
$pdf->Ln();
$pdf->SetX(20);
$pdf->SetFont('Times','',12);   
$pdf->Cell(170,6,'Your Signature:_____________________________ ','LR');

}                                   
// encode data (puts attachment in proper format)
$pdfdoc = $pdf->Output("", "S");
$attachment = chunk_split(base64_encode($pdfdoc));

// main header
$headers  = 'From: noreply@emailaddress here ' . $eol;
$headers .= '"MIME-Version: 1.0' . $eol;
$headers .= 'Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="' . $separator .'"';

// no more headers after this, we start the body! //

$body  = '--' . $separator . $eol;
$body .= 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit' . $eol . $eol;
//$body .= "This is a MIME encoded message.".$eol;

// message
$body .= '--' . $separator . $eol;
$body .= 'Content-Type: text/html; charset="iso-8859-1"' . $eol;
$body .= 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit' . $eol . $eol;
$body .= $message . $eol;

// attachment
$body .= '--' . $separator . $eol;
$body .= 'Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name="MCLE.pdf"' . $eol;
$body .= 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64' . $eol;
$body .= 'Content-Disposition: attachment' . $eol . $eol;
$body .= $attachment . $eol;
$body .= '--' . $separator . '--';
mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers) ;

unset($pdf);  // destroy PDF object
?>
<script>
alert('Emails Successfully Sent !');
history.back();
</script>
<?php

} // end of foreach through $_POST['email']

}  // end of isset($_POST['submit'])/////////////
?>
```